# Slow SDK download through Android SDK manager

Tags: android, sdk, download, android-build

When I run Android SDK manager to download SDK platform, the download speed is 8 KiB/s. It would take more than 2 hours to download one platform like Android 2.2, API 8. There is no problem with download stuff through browser. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. My internet connection is FTTC (typically about 15 Mbps) but all day I've been getting no more than 100 KiB/s when the Android SDK and AVD Manager is downloading archives.

Comment: 7 years later (API 27) and still having the same problem... amazing

Answer (score 30):

I have not experienced this issue. Force or unforce HTTPS (there is an option for this under Settings), and see if this improves the quality of your connection.

Comment: I am sure you googled the issue, perhaps you can try disabling auto tuning on your network adapter by running "netsh interface tcp set global autotuning=disabled" in the command prompt, assuming you are using windows

[link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/12cd670ed8886256?pli=1)

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. Downloading the files manually from xml is very fast but using the sdk manager is very slow. Also it's not always clear where the files go after manual dl as adding them to the most obvious location doesn't make them appear in the SDK manager sometimes.

Comment: It works, unless it is being blocked by a antivirus for https check

Comment: Worked for me too, download speed went from ~300KiB/s, to ~17000KiB/s

Answer (score 23):

I also have this problems and found a solution online and it looks like it working for now. I tried with forcing HTTP AND HTTPS and nothing really work.

So try this:

1.) Run command prompt as an administator - Windows 7 (Start->Right click on Command Prompt-> Choose "Run as Administrator") or "Start" enter CMD into search box and then right click and "Run as administrator".

2.) In Command Prompt window enter:

```
netsh
```

and press ENTER

3.) Then write this and hit ENTER at the end:

```
interface tcp set global autotuning=disabled
```

4.) Now restart your SDK manager and try to download again!

---

**Before** doing the above, Take note of your *original* value in case you want to revert back:

```
interface tcp show global
```

Comment: I tried this solution and if anything it made things worse. Please could you put up the undo instructions for solutions like this? I imagine I just set it to enabled but I have no idea.

Comment: Well it worked fine for me not sure about the "undo" settings but i guess you need to change global autotuning back to normal. Check here:
http://www.speedguide.net/articles/windows-7-vista-2008-tweaks-2574 Read bellow: TCP Auto-Tuning title. But like i said try to set it back on "normal" state.

Comment: @AtulD seriously 1mb! But this answer did not help me.

Comment: Combination of both this method and http worked for me! Waited so long to download.. But now its super fast !

Answer (score 13):

Try disabling antivirus and enabling `Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://...` in Android SDK Manager's `Tools-> Options...`.

This helped me.

Comment: helped me, I tried the accepted answer's method but it didn't help me, but this method did help me indeed

Comment: Doing this (in the standalone SDK Manager otherwise used by Android Studio 2.1) increased download speed from 25kbps to about 1500 kbps.  I.e., it was about 60 times as fast.  This is the difference between a two hour download and a two minute download.

Comment: This is a gem. worked for me. Download speed moved from 85bit/s to 3MB/s

Answer (score 7):

Unchecking the https box worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Check those XML file links
[image: Check those Xml file links]

Let me pen them down here...

[Google Repository for SDK's Of all Android API](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml)

[Google Repository for Add-on's (Google API's) for all Android API](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml)

[Intel API's for Android](http://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/android/addon.xml)

[Google repository for system Images](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img.xml)

[MIPS repository for system images](http://www.mips.com/global/sdk-sys-img.xml)

[Intel repository for system images](http://download-software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/android/sys-img.xml)

Now you will know what you must be looking out for....

Take an example of this snapshot[image: Say i want to download google API for Android API12]

Say i want to download google API for Android API12

then [Google Repository for Add-on's (Google API's) for all Android API](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml) 
Lookup for `<sdk:url>` tag under `<sdk:addon>` tag as given in the example below

[image: Look up for the sdk:url tag]

and then use the link used to obtain the XML file

Strip off the last part and replace it with the `<sdk:url>` tag content

for eg: in this case it would be like

[Google API for Android API 12 (HoneyComb)](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_apis-12_r01.zip)

there you have a download link....

Similarly SDK's ,System-images can be downloaded....

Dont have to wait for ages to complete that list ;) for you download to get accelerated use DAP or IDM ( download accelerators )

Enjoy! :)

Comment: The first image is obtained from the Android SDK log

Comment: FWIW, this didn't work for me. I'm still experiencing very slow downloads.

Comment: @dnissley Arent you feeding the download link to an accelerator like IDM ?

Comment: @shridatt, How did you draw those red circles?

Comment: @Pacerier MS Paint :D

Comment: @shridatt, Wow, didn't know that program could do graphics.

Comment: @Pacerier ill take that as a compliment :3

Answer (score 3):

You can manually download and install Android SDK Component.

Method:

**STEP 1**- Go to android SDK installation folder("C:\Users\%username%\Appdata\Local\Android\android-SDK" or any other location you choose during installation) then open android SDK manager
[image]
**STEP 2**- Check the Component you want to download
[image]
**STEP 3**- Then click on install 1 package
[image]
[image]
**STEP 4**- Click on stop button 
[image]
**STEP 5**- Navigate to android SDK installation folder then go to temp  ("C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\temp") folder here you will see two files are created copy the name of the set up information file
[image]
**STEP 6**- goto web browser and type url https://dl.google.com/android/repository/(file name you copied)
in my case https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-23_r01.zip
[image]
**STEP 7** - A file will be downloaded automatically
[image]
**STEP 8**- After download is finished go to "C:\Users\%username%\Appdata\Local\Android\android-sdk\temp" and delete the two files created there and paste the downloaded file there
[image]
[image]
**STEP 9**- Now go to android SDK manager and check the component again and click on  install 1 package
[image]
**STEP 10**- The package will be installed automatically
[image]
[image]

Comment: "http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/(copied file name)" while downloading system image e.g-http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/x86_64-24_r07.zip

Comment: The standalone SDK Manager has since been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

After working on this for weeks and trying all the above plus other suggestions around the web, I came up with the following solution:

1) Remove PC Tools Firewall Plus

2) Remove AVG free antivirus

3) Install Comodo Internet Security Free.

The files are downloading and installing fine now. I'm also using HTTP mode as suggested. If you have any of the above security tools I recommend giving this a try. BTW, turning off PC Tools will not be enough.

Answer (score 1):

None of the other solutions listed here resolved the issue for me, not even uninstalling Android Studio/SDK and then reinstalling them. It's worth noting that the standalone SDK Manager has also been **deprecated** since a lot of these answers were posted.

After hours of troubleshooting, I managed to resolve the issue by renaming my Android Studio config folder (`~/.AndroidStudio2.3`) to something else and making Android Studio create it again. You can ask Android Studio to import your old `config` and it still works, so it's likely something to do with the `system` folder.

Hope this helps anyone else that is having this issue but was unable to find a solution like myself.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem plus google don't allow me to access andriod, and I must connect with a VPN. so I download all xmls and package that I need to my localhost and set dl-ssl.google.com too 127.0.0.1 and then I install them from my local with extra speed :D

Comment: for this solution you must an web server application installed, it is stupid way but worked for me

Answer (score -4):

I also have this problems and found a solution online and it looks like it working for now. I tried with forcing HTTP AND HTTPS and nothing really work.

So try this:

1.) Run command prompt as an administator - Windows 7 (Start->Right click on Command Prompt-> Choose "Run as Administrator") or "Start" enter CMD into search box and then right click and "Run as administrator".

2.) In Command Prompt window enter (everything without quotes): 'netsh' and press ENTER

3.) Then write this and hit ENTER at the end: interface tcp set global autotuning=disabled

4.) Now restart your SDK manager and try to download again!