# what is Linux equivalent of "netsh interface tcp set global autotuning=disabled" command?

Tags: tcp, sdk, download, ubuntu-14.04

I want to download the Android SDK with the SDK manager in Ubuntu 14.0.4. My internet bandwidth is 10 megabits per second, but Android SDK manager download speed is too low.

There was a solution for it in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419989/slow-sdk-download-through-android-sdk-manager), the command is:

```
netsh interface tcp set global autotuning=disabled
```

but this is for windows. What is the equivalent command for Linux (Ubuntu)?