# Android Studio slow download during setup

Tags: android, android-studio

I wanted to install Android Studio as I'm new to Android programming but after initial install, it downloads the packages sooooo slowly compared to normal downloads on my home internet.

Things I've tried:

- installing packages through the SDK manager but the download speed is the same, reporting 10KB/s.
- these old answers: [Slow SDK download through Android SDK manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419989/slow-sdk-download-through-android-sdk-manager)
- placing my PC in my routers DMZ
- removing my router to directly connect to my modem
- other compters

Is there a completely offline install for Android studio, like other software (i.e. Google Chrome)? Then I could use a download manager to get it quickly.

[image: ss]

Comment: maybe its temporary problem, try to restart the setup

Comment: I've forced closed it in task manager and restarted my computer but still downloading slowly

Comment: Fixed it, it was my internet connection, used a completely different internet connection and now it is complete.

Comment: so maybe its your ISP problem

Comment: yeah something is a bit weird. I can download full speed though from from GDrive, Play store etc, I'll just leave it for now

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes the slowness is also related to antivirus.

In my case, *Java Platform* was doing all the download process in the background when using *Android SDK Manager*.

[image]

If someone is experiencing a slow download, an alternative is forcing Android SDK Manager to use http connection and not https.

The download process itself is really annoying, takes forever anyway as we can notice. There should be mirrors for those files to accelerate this download process.

[image]

Comment: Using `http` instead of `https` is also speeding up the download of `Android SDK IDE` and documentation download. From 130 kbps -> 1.6 MB (Your max Internet connection speed)

Comment: Using http instead of https is the solution guys.

Answer (score 3):

Disable https AND disable use cache solved the problem for me

Answer (score 2):

Copy the download link 
And paste it in chrome's address bar if you have IDM it it will ask you to download it.[image]

Comment: What should I do with the downloaded file?

Answer (score 1):

Check on "force https" in the SDK Manager settings.

Comment: it should be a comment.